# How to iterate through 2 columns with different step for each from a Dataframe to calculate the average of a third column?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, tuples

I have a dataframe [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6zAB.jpg) containing x, y, vx, vy and I want to calculate the mean of vx and the mean of vy in 2D boxes something like:

```
for x in range (0,330,16):
  for y in range (0,600,100):
     mean=vx.mean()
     mean2=vy.mean()
     mean3=sqrt(mean**2+mean2**2)
     MeanVx.append(mean)
     MeanVy.append(mean2)
     MeanVm.append(mean3)
```

I was able to do it in 1D over x using the following code:

```
i=0.0
height=np.ceil(max(vels["x"]))
height1=np.ceil(max(vels["y"]))
print(height)
MeanVx=[]
MeanVy=[]
MeanVm=[]

steps=18.18       #The width of the area
steps1=36.36
while (np.round(i)<= height):
    filter_vels = vels[(i <= vels.x) & (vels.x<= i+steps)] #calculating the x intervals in px
    mean=filter_vels["vx"].mean()*2.75   #in µm/s avraging all values of vx present on a given x
    mean3=filter_vels["vy"].mean()*2.75
    mean4=sqrt(mean**2+mean3**2)
    MeanVx.append(mean)
    MeanVy.append(mean3)
    MeanVm.append(mean4)
    i=i+steps

rangeX= np.linspace(0,np.ceil(height),len(MeanVx)) #in px
```

I can't find a way to apply it to 2D. Thank you!!

mean velocities in each box in the image

[image: plots]
[image: plots]

Comment: Could you provide an example of you tuples?

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen thank you for your comment, please excuse my very limited experience in python but I double checked and I think I'm working with a DataFrame and not a tuple. I'll add a pic of the head and correct my mistake.

Comment: Yeah, that's a dataframe! A tuple is just a python collection that looks like `(1, 2, 3)`. In the future, when you post some data on Stack Overflow, you'll want to use text, by printing it with `print(my_dataframe)`. As for your question, could explain in words a bit further exactly what it is that you want? What do you mean by "the mean in 2D boxes?".

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen noted thank you, as you see I'm not that experienced. The idea is to calculate the average of Vx and the average of Vy inside boxes as shown in figure 1. The logic goes like this: for x between 0 and 50 and for y between 0 and 100 calculate the average, the, for w between 0 and 50 and for y between 100 and 200 calculate average... when iteration over x between 0,50 is done it moves to 50-100 and iterates over y ranges...2D boxes refers to x,y dimensions. I'm very thankful for your interest!